# Errors in android application with OutputStreamWriter

Tags: java, android

I am trying to figure out what my problem is with some code in an Android app. I am trying to write some text from an EditText (a couple of boxes). I have two errors, and have looked over it time and time again, and cannot figure out where I have gone wrong. I probable have stared at it too long.

The line I have errors at is specifically the bolded text. Also, **directory.close()**

file = new FileOutputStream(**view**);
                    OutputStreamWriter outputstreamwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(**file**);

Code:

```
 try

            {
                File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Car/");
                directory.mkdirs();
                File file = new File(directory, "Car.txt");
                file.createNewFile();
                **file = new FileOutputStream(view);
                OutputStreamWriter outputstreamwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(file);**
                outputstreamwriter.append((new StringBuilder()).append(txtName.getText()).append("\n").append("\n").toString());
                outputstreamwriter.append((new StringBuilder()).append(txtAddress.getText()).append("\n").append("\n").toString());
                outputstreamwriter.append((new StringBuilder()).append(txtEmail.getText()).append("\n").append("\n").toString());
                outputstreamwriter.append((new StringBuilder()).append(txtPhone.getText()).append("\n").append("\n").toString());
                outputstreamwriter.append((new StringBuilder()).append(txtDesc.getText()).append("\n").append("\n").toString());
                outputstreamwriter.close();
                directory.close();
            }
            // Misplaced declaration of an exception variable
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "balls", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

I appreciate any help or insight you can provide.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked that you have the permission needed to write external storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- > Closes the stream, flushing it first.

I think you should do `outputStreamWriter.flush()` firstly, then close it.
[OutputStreamWriter.close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#close())

- You should provide the exact error stack trace.

Comment: Thank you. I think I got it.